# An inquiry regarding Java classes objects and data transfer from one activity to another in Android

Tags: java, android, class, object

So I'm making an Android app and I've got one `ListView` (called `showclients`) that links to another (called `ViewClient`). When `showclients` is called, it gathers a bunch of data from other java classes and stores it in an object of type `ClientList` (which I've made).

`ViewClient` needs that info and it takes way too long to get it from scratch again, so in `showclients` I made a `public static` variable called `Clist` of type `ClientList` and made a method...

```
public static ClientList returnobj(){
    return Clist;
}
```

Back in `ViewClient` I called

```
ClientList grief= showclients.returnobj();
```

and it gets me the data. I want to know why that works and if it'll work on Java without Android.

Comment: Is `showclients` the name of the class, and if not, what is?

Comment: It's a class that extends Activity.

Answer (score 1):

so you are asking how to share data between activities. one option is to host your data model in your application class. create a class that extends `Application`,

```
public MyApplication extends Application { ...
```

in your manifest, add your application class,

```
   <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...
```

the lifecycle of the `Application` class allows you to host your data there. it lives beyond the starting / stopping on any particular activity. add private members to your `MyApplication` class, and provide getters and setters to access the data,

```
public MyApplication extends Application {
  private MyData myData;

  public MyData getMyData() { return myData; }
  public void setMyData(MyData data) { this.myData = data; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your sample code is a bit confusing though but I think I get this. Does this data die when the app closes?

Comment: define "app closes". it lives beyond the starting and stopping of any particular activity. the data is obviously not persistent as android can destroy your app's process to make room for other things. if you need persistence, you should look into using sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your Problem?

What means 'Java without Android' ?
Since ListView, Activity and so on are Android specific I'd say no.

But your 'Concept' should/could work without Android. -> Please more Info...

IMHO your description is a bit cryptic... maybe post some more code.

Comment: I have code from one activity that I want to use in another. It works but I don't know why. In the first one I have  public static ClientList Clist= new ClientList(objectinput,0); and the method above. When I go to the second I just use the bit of code with grief in it and I got all the data gathered before, I don't know why.

Comment: Your Activity lives on if another Activity is active, so you can still get the data from the other. But you may loose your data if your app gets 'destroyed' by the Android OS

Comment: an Activity has a lifecycle, this means when your Activity gets shown for the first time, it get's created. Then it gets stored in RAM as long as possible, because creating an Activity is power consuming. But if Android thinks it needs more Memory and your Activitiy is not in use, it 'destroys' your Activity. This means your Instance of your Activity is lost and so are all membervariables which are not `static`. So if you make it static, it lifes on. For more info see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether **this exact code** will work by compiling and running it on Java SE (i.e. "without Android"), then **no**, since Java SE does not have some classes that you use (like `Activity`).

For graphical user interfaces in Java SE, you should a library like [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing) or [SWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWT).

If you're asking whether **the general scheme of transferring data** will work on Java SE, then **yes, it will**. The reason is exactly you using the `static` keyword. This means that the static "variable" (actually a *member*) and the static method is defined for the entire `showclients` class, and not any of its objects in particular. That means that everywhere in your program, the value of the static member is the same, and `returnobj()` will return the same object.

Without the `static` keyword, the value would exist once for each object of `showclients` you create, and not the class as a whole.

That's one of the reasons why your solution works on Android - if the value would not be stored in a static member, you would have to reference the actual `showclients` object, which could get removed from memory at any time while your other Activity is showing (because a background Activity, `showclients` in this case, can be removed at any time). Because the member is static, it hangs around as long as `showclients` is loaded by the Java Virtual Machine, which for your purposes is as long as you need.

Finally, **Jeffrey's** solution is much better for Android code, since you're not abusing the definition of an `Activity` for additional functionality that should be placed in a [dedicated piece of code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). In Java SE you would implement a similar solution by creating a new class implementing the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). And, actually, `MyApplication` in Jeffrey's examples is a singleton for the purpose of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about static keyword? Static methods (or variables) are bound directly to class itself, not its particular instance. It's better to show on example, but with variable (do not use it this way, read about encapsulation):

```
class A {
  public static String foo = "foo";

  public A() {
    foo = "bar";
  }
}

class B {
  public void something() {
    // suppose print exists
    print(A.foo); // prints foo

    A a = new A();
    print(A.foo); // prints bar
    print(a.foo); // prints bar
  }
}
```

Make yourself some simple java application (that's the one w